# What does the "lvalue to rvalue" conversion mean for std::decay?

Tags: c++, rvalue

I am confused about the wording for `std::decay` on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay). They say it applies "lvalue to rvalue." I know `std::decay` removes referenceness, so is this what they mean by that? If so, why is a non-reference type called an rvalue?

Comment: at the bottom of the page you link there is a link to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion.

Comment: A roundabout way of saying "strips reference-ness", I think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think cppreference is just using the term a bit loosely and makes an assumption that the reader is aware of the connection between refererence kinds and value categories.

Normally an implicit conversion is something that is applied to an *expression*, not to a *type*.

A conversion is something like "*An lvalue/xvalue/prvalue expression of type `T` may be converted to an lvalue/xvalue/prvalue expression of type `U`.*" followed by a specification of how the result of the conversion is determined.

Notably, types of expressions (i.e. `T` and `U`) are never reference types. However, there is a canonical mapping from the value category (lvalue/xvalue/prvalue) to reference kinds:

```
lvalue <-> lvalue reference
xvalue <-> rvalue reference
prvalue <-> no reference
```

And with that translation there is an analogues meaning for a conversion on a *type* that matches exactly what you would get when applying `decltype` to the expression before and after the conversion.

An lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is a conversion from a non-function, non-array lvalue or xvalue of type `cv T` to a prvalue of either type `cv T` if `T` is a class type or `T` if `T` is not a class type.

So in terms of the type analogy this means that `cv T&` and `cv T&&` are transformed to `cv T` if `T` is a class type and to `T` if `T` is a non-function non-array non-class type. And in all other situations no transformation is applied (at least not due to the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion part of the explanation of `std::decay`).

Of course, because `cv` qualifiers are removed in a second step, this means effectively simply that references and cv-qualifiers are removed. However, for function and array types `std::decay` behaves slightly differently, because it applies the array-to-pointer and function-to-pointer conversion with the same analogy and therefore produces a function pointer or an element pointer instead of a function type or array type (however ref/cv-qualified). The description on cppreference makes it clear that `std::decay` reflects the behavior of these implicit conversions on type and value category.

---

In the above `cv` is any combination of `const` and `volatile` (or neither).